# Mysql how to add more than one value (in one box)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add more than one value

```
INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
05, 'Exotic Weapons''basic weapon');
```

is that possible? i have all ready tried `|` and `&` but i am not allowed to do that.

the idea is to demonstrate that `item_ID` requires more than one Sname.

and if no `SName` are needed, how do i code that, in the `alter table` it shows me that they are by default '0' for `item_ID` and '' for `Sname`, but when i try:

```
 INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
    02, '');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 
02, );
```

error occurs. `item_ID` and `SName` are the primary key and foreign key to two different tables

```
CREATE TABLE `requierments` (
  `item_ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SName` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_ID`,`SName`),
  KEY `SName` (`SName`),
  CONSTRAINT `requierments_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item_ID`) REFERENCES `item` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `requierments_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`SName`) REFERENCES `talents` (`SkillName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `talents` (
  `SkillName` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Bonus` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Str` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_WS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_BS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Fel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Per` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Int` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_Agi` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `R_WP` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Talent_requiret` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SkillName`),
  KEY `Talent_requiret` (`Talent_requiret`),
  CONSTRAINT `talents_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Talent_requiret`) REFERENCES `talents` (`SkillName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Name_` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Weight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Value_` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Availability` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here are the 3 tables where i want to store in the requirement table what `item_ID` requires to be used under `SName`, since one item can be required to have more than one `SName` or none, it get confused on what to do.

Comment: I would point out that you spelled Requirements wrong. Then again, it appears you spelled it wrong in your creation code, too, so that isn't your problem.

Comment: hehe yeah notest, but keep it that way. the connection between the tables seems to be fine, the issue is that i want the items to have more than one talent required or one to be used. and that information stored in the requierment table. what item requires what

Answer (score 1):

The `'Exotic Weapons''basic weapon'` syntax is interpreted as `'Exotic Weapons'basic weapon'` (see the [manual page on String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)). You can store both, if you separate them with a special character like a comma or something (`'Exotic Weapons,basic weapon'`), but this is a bad idea, for the reasons that follow.

Anytime you are tempted to store multiple values in one column, you should have a new table to store each value and link it to the `item_ID` in question. This is called "normalization" - it makes your database more stable, your application code simpler, and everything just more likely to work as you move forward and modify things. Search for "database normalization" and read about how to do the kind of thing you are trying to do.

**EDIT:** It's still a little hard to tell what you're trying to do, but it looks like you just want to store multiple tuples in `items`. Example:

```
INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES
    (5, 'Exotic Weapons'),
    (5, 'basic weapon');
```

Note that it should be `5`, not `05`. That's why `INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 02, '');` fails. Also, you can't just omit a value and have blank space, like in your other example: `INSERT INTO Requierments (item_ID, SName) VALUES ( 02, );`

Honestly, it's very hard to tell what you're even trying to do here, and there seems to be some confusion about the basics of table structure and SQL syntax. For example, this statement is very confusing and unclear: "since one item can be required to have more than one SName or none, it get confused on what to do." If you can provide some more clarity about how you want the tables to relate to each other and where you are stuck, you will get more help from the SO community.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how can i then code that no SName is not required? since i can't do ''?

Comment: Not correct.  As documented under [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html): "*A “`'`” inside a string quoted with “`'`” may be written as “`''`”.*"

Comment: So i have read about the normalization rules, and i see the point. but what i cant figure out is how do i add more than one SName to one item_ID. the point is that item_ID may require more than one SName, and some may not require any at all. how do i do that?

Comment: The point is to put them in separate tables. Have a table that tracks the item ids (and any other information particular to the item), one that stores the various names, and one that matches item ids to the names (by id). It's hard to give a more precise recommendation without understanding more about what data you want to store. But storing multiple values in one column is definitely not the way to do it.

Comment: i have typed in the code, for the creation on those 3 tables on my first post. hope i clarifies it a bit

Comment: I have added more detail to my answer.

Comment: @eggyal: You're right, but that's not the syntax used above. My point is that `'foo''bar'` is invalid syntax. I have tweaked my answer to avoid misleading anyone.

Comment: My point was merely that `'foo''bar'` is perfectly valid *syntactically*, even if in this case it is not correct *semantically*'.

Comment: @eggyal: I see what you're saying, and you have a good point; I will tweak my answer. Thanks.